# Build failed with bytecode error in Android Studio

Tags: android, okhttp, dex

I have this error:

[image: Gradle build failed issue]

I have enabled multidex but still it gives me multidex files define issues.

```
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        // Navigation Drawer Library
        compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        // Debugger Tools libraries
        debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
        debugCompile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2'
        //Google, Inc (Play services) Libraries
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'

        // Google, Inc (Support) Libraries
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
        // Parse Server API SDK
        compile project(':ParseUI-Widget')
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
        compile 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
        // Facebook, Inc SDKs
        compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.18.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
        // Libraries for loading images
        compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:0.11.0+'
        compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.0'
        // Location Helper Library
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
        // Time library
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
        // Accelaration library
        //compile 'com.neumob:neumob-android:3.2.4'
        // Others
        compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile files('libs/mint-4.4.0.jar')
```

I have added build.gradle file.

I don't know how to solve Multidex issue in Android. My app has lots of SDKs integration, I went through lots of tutorials and blogs. I got so many solutions. One of them is below mentioned as part of my gradle.

Comment: i have added in question now.

Comment: Can I ask why you rolled back to revision 2? I was only trying to make your `build.gradle` file easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```